# Splitting a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a fake data frame below, and try to manipulate the 'contact' column. some people have only phone numbers, some only have emails, some have both number and email with a space in between.

So, I want to create two more columns ('gender' and 'email') and split the contact column in 3 columns. ('gender'- (M) into Male and (F) into Female, 'phone_number', and 'email')

I tried

```
df = (df.set_index(cols)['contact'].str.split(' ',expand=True).stack()
```

but I failed because some times it has a space between (F) and the phone number after it.

```
employee = {'EmployeeID' : [0,1,2],
         'FirstName' : ['a','b','c'],
         'LastName' : ['a','b','c'],
         'MiddleName' : ['a','b, None],
         'Contact' : ['(M) 133-245-3123', '(F)a123@gmail.com', '(F)312-533-2442 jimmy234@gmail.com']}

df = pd.DataFrame(employee)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex,

```
df[['gender','phone_number','email']]=df['Contact'].str.\
extract('\(([A-Z])\)\s?(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})?\s?(.*)', expand = False)
df.drop('Contact', axis = 1, inplace = True)


    EmployeeID  FirstName   LastName    MiddleName  gender  phone_number    email
0   0           a           a           a           M       133-245-3123    
1   1           b           b           b           F       NaN             a123@gmail.com
2   2           c           c           None        F       312-533-2442    jimmy234@gmail.com
```